# Unable to retrieve column information: No colum information was returned by the sql command

Tags: ssis

I am using Microsoft sql server 2008, I tried all the 3 solutions, but every time I get the same error

```
Error at Data Flow Task[OLEDB source[449]]:No colum information was returned by the sql command
```

I am using the following batch of sql statments to retrieve the server level configuration of all servers in my company. The table variable `@tb1_SvrStng` has 83 columns and it is populated using different resources.

So I summarize the sql script. I cannot use it as stored procedure because this script is going to run against 14 servers (once for each server).  So if I store the procedure on one server, other server cannot execute that procedure in its context.

I will highly appreciate your help.  I am not using any temporary table in my script.

```
declare @tb1_SvrStng table 
( 
srvProp_MachineName varchar(50), 
srvProp_BldClrVer varchar(50), 
srvProp_Collation varchar(50), 
srvProp_CNPNB varchar(100), 
... 
xpmsver_ProdVer varchar(50),
..... . 
syscnfg_UsrCon_cnfgVal int,
..... 
); 
insert into @tb1_SvrStng 
( 
srvProp_BldClrVer, 
srvProp_Collation, 
srvProp_CNPNB , ........ 
........ . 
) 
select convert(varchar, serverproperty('BuildClrVer')), 
convert(varchar, serverproperty('Collation')) 
........
....... 
declare @temp_msver1 table 
( 
id int, name varchar(100), 
........... 
); 

insert into @temp_msver1 exec xp_msver 
Update @tb1_SvrStng 
set xpmsver_ProdVer = 
( 
select value from @temp_msver1 where name = 'ProductVersion' 
), 
xpmsver_Platform = 
( 
select value from @temp_msver1 where name = 'Platform' 
), 
.....
...... 
select 
srvProp_SerName as srvProp_SerName, 
getdate() as reportDateTime, 
srvProp_BldClrVer as srvProp_BldClrVer, 
srvProp_Collation as srvProp_Collation, 
..... 
..... 
from @tb1_SvrStng
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can gather from your code and question is that the query cannot be processed outside runtime, because you're doing something dynamic to it, or that it won't process it since it's doing something funky.

One trick to this would be to use the Source component in the data flow task to something "dummy" - which you can fake with a query like this

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(DATATYPE,NULL) AS srvProp_SerName, 
CONVERT(DATETIME,NULL) AS reportDateTime, 
CONVERT(DATATYPE,NULL) AS srvProp_BldClrVer, 
CONVERT(DATATYPE,NULL) AS srvProp_Collation
```

This way the source component should be able to read the metadata. You can then put your proper query (as long as it's within the limits of the length of the query text) into a variable, and then assign this as an expression to the source component.

At runtime it will then use the expression query - and hopefully don't mind too much the metadata issue.

This may or may not work but it should be worth a try since it won't take long to confirm.